# Why is the page title not not changing in a turbo-ios app

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, turbo, turbo-ios

In a Ruby on Rails app, I am setting the title by the following code in the head tag

`<title><%= @title %></title>`

where @title is set in the controller action for each page. Running as a web-app, this works fine.  But if I run it as a turbo-ios app, when I navigate from page to page, the title does not change from the title of the starting page. I have made no modifications to the standard turbo-ios SceneDelegate class, apart from setting a custom user agent.

According to the [turbo-ios documentation](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-ios/blob/main/Docs/Overview.md)

"By default, Turbo iOS sets your Visitable view controller’s title property to the page’s title."

So why is this happening and how do I fix this?

I have also taken the [turbo-ios demo app](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-native-demo) and altered the definitions of `basic` and `turbolinks5` in `Demo.swift` to point to my app, and I can navigate between pages but the title does not change.

**Update**

I have found that if I remove this tag from the `<head>`

```
<%= turbo_include_tags %>
```

it fixes the problem and also presents the `<` navigation link (back) in the top section of app. So it looks like the problem is with Turbo Drive. I need to use Turbo Drive, so is there a work around?

Comment: As per the Turbo iOS documentation, "Turbo Drive avoids updating the Turbo iOS view controller's title property by default to avoid unnecessary re-rendering and navigation gestures." This means that Turbo Drive intentionally suppresses the automatic title updates to maintain the smooth navigation experience.

Comment: This contribution, https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/issues/600#issue-1265329302, addresses the issue of title not updating for turbo frames, I am wondering if a similar approach could be used for turbo-ios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Maniac's comment above, the Turbo documentation states that "Turbo Drive avoids updating the Turbo iOS view controller's title property by default to avoid unnecessary re-rendering and navigation gestures."

However, when I implemented a native top menu using [strada-ios](https://github.com/hotwired/strada-ios)
the title changes correctly without adding any code to do this.